# Passing arguments into the Class: unpacking during definition or in the constructor in python3?

Tags: class, oop, python-3.6

I'm new to OOP and writing the main.py. Called from the CLI by passing many different arguments.

Please help me to use the better solution to unpack the values?

Solution #1: unpack arguments during class definition or Solution #2: to unpack arguments in the **init** constructor.

Solution#1

```
def unpack_command_line(vars):
      if len(vals) == 3:
          return dictinary_of_some_values1
      elif len(vals) > 4:
          return dictinary_of_some_values2
      else:
          raise ValueError("Some arguments are missing")


def main(argv):
      cli_vars = unpack_command_line(argv)
      if cli_vars['action'] == 'some_command':
           sc = SomeClass(cli_vars['param1'], cli_vars['param'])
           sc.domesomething()
      if cli_vars['action'] == 'some_command2':
           .........
      else:
           raise ValueError("Wrong arguments")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

And after I'm calling a class

```
class SomeCLass():

    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
```

Solution#2

```
def unpack_command_line(vars):
      if len(vals) == 3:
          return dictinary_of_some_values1
      elif len(vals) > 4:
          return dictinary_of_some_values2
      else:
          raise ValueError("Some arguments are missing")


def main(argv):
      cli_vars = unpack_command_line(argv) 
      if cli_vars['action'] == 'some_command': 
           sc = SomeClass(cli_vars)  # Here is the difference 1
           sc.domesomething()
      if cli_vars['action'] == 'some_command2':
         .......
      else:
           raise ValueError("Wrong arguments")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

And after I'm calling a class

```
class SomeCLass():

    def __init__(self, dict_cli_vars):   # Here is the difference 2
        self.param1 = dict_cli_vars['param1']  # Here is the difference 3
        self.param2 = dict_cli_vars['param2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later *i.e.* unpacking in the constructor is the better approach. You can unpack contents of the `cli_vars` dictionary.

```
sc = SomeClass(**cli_vars)


class SomeCLass():

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):   # Here is the difference 2
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, val)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer @OluwafemiSule, but how do I use those unpacked values?

Comment: Since unpacked values are set as instance attributes in the constructor they can be accessed in any defined instance method. Does this answer your question?

Comment: please nvm made a typo while checking your response. Thank you @OluwafemiSule